# Anular CSS da class ui-disable

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma `navbar` como `footer`.

O primeiro elemento da `navbar` tem a classe `ui-disabled` para não ser possivel interagir com ele.

Aqui está o [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2d9ttym/5/)

**HTML/JQuery**

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toogle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="b">
                    <ul>
                       <li class="ui-disabled"><a id="listSO_options">Opções</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "ui-btn-active  nav" href="#">menu</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" id="listSO_btnDef" data-icon="gear">Definições</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
</div><!-- footer -->
```

**Pergunta**

Como se nota no fiddle, o primeiro elemento está mais desbotado que os dois seguintes. É possível, usando **CSS** e mantendo o primeiro elemento com a classe `ui-disabled` torna-lo idêntico aos restantes `li`'s ?

Caso tenho sido pouco explícito: é possivel anular o **CSS** caracteristico da classe `ui-disabled`?

Comment: Uma solução seria você copiar o CSS da classe ui-disable, colocar no seu arquivo css com outro nome e associar essa nova classe ao seu li. Assim você poderia alterar o css dele sem perder a propriedade original. Já tentou isso? Ficaria algo como <li class="ui-disabledNovaClasse"><a id="listSO_options">Opções</a></li>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença é que o disabled tem `opacity: .3;`, repondo a opacity para 1 resolve o problema.

Usando

```
$('[data-role="navbar"] li:first').css('opacity', 1);
```

resolve o problema.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2d9ttym/6/

Se resolveres aplicar cia classe de CSS tens de usar `!important;` para sobrepôr a regra. Usando via JavaScript como referi em cima não é preciso pois aplicando no elemento ele tem prioridade.

Comment: Criei em **CSS** e resultou como disseste. Obrigado. Eu estava a tentar adicionar agora no **CSS** também o `pointer-events: auto !important;` para testar, mas o **CSS** não aceita. Sabes explicar-me porque? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u2d9ttym/8/)

Comment: @msm.oliveira o que queres que aconteça com `pointer-events: auto !important;`? qual é o comportamento que queres?

Comment: acabei mesmo agora de o resolver XD. obrigado

Comment: @msm.oliveira ok, boa! estive fora e só agora cheguei ao PC. Bom que já está resolvido.